Incommensurable (or irrationals) nature in depth
Studying on how incommensurability were first discovered in Greece and how real numbers therory was established by Dedekind and others, something did not get closed in my mind about incommensurable measures (or irrational numbers). I am really fascinated by the phenomenon of their existence and tried to find some material that better explained their nature.
However, everything I found is the very same proof that square root of two cannot be rational, so incommensurable measures exist and that is it. They were accepted as magnitudes or numbers, all algebra and calculus were developed relying on their existence, and in 19th century it was definitely demonstrated that they really could be treated arithmetically and algebraically.
Well, that are much information that I were (partially) learned along the time. But I was not able to find a reference that explained WHY, i.e., why incommensurable magnitudes appear in a deeper way. Are they consequence of Euclid geometry's axioms? Thinking only on commensurable magnitudes as ancient Greek did (i.e., assuming that there are only rational numbers), what is so special in a square's diagonal or the ratio of a circle's circumference and diameter that makes their calculation never end?
Every text I have read say that they never end and that is it, not going deeper into why. I am not a mathematician, I have a degree in computer science instead. So my question should be interpreted as a beginner question as, even knowing partially about one or two topics, I may missed some basic (or not so that) point.
I am not wandering about the existence of irrationals in a mathematical sense, I do know that they exist and their existence was proved consistent. I ask on the deep nature of incommensurability based on Euclid's axioms. I know that Euclid's geometry is an abstract model, a mathematical construction, so the properties that devise from it could be somehow dissected.
As far I know, nobody yet did that on the specific problem I proposed. Everybody just say 'they exist, here's the proof, deal with that' but do not explore the properties on how they cause the incommensurability existence. Also, I intentionally used ancient terms to try not to create bias towards the modern point of view. I really wanted one puts himself at ancient Greece and thought from the problems they faced, even if only modern math could explain the things.
PS. Please be polite when pointing problems with the question. I am willing to help to clarify only for those who do not use harsh words. As I said, I am not a mathematician, so be patient.

Try to use modern terminology. You clearly know the term "irrational number," so don't keep using the obsolete "incommensurable measure." Measure, in particular, means something specific to mathematicians now, and it just makes your question hard to read.

And what does "exist" mean, for a number? I mean, we can easily write a real number which is irrational, simply by writing in base 10 a decimal number which does repeat. We can easily show rational numbers always repeat in their decimal expansion. But does that non-repeating number "exist?"

The reason you don't understand is because you think mathematicians are interested in some "truth" about the universe. What mathematicians do is show that if the real line has certain properties, then irrationals must exist. These desired properties are somewhat intuitive for the real world, but we have no evidence numbers of any sort exist in the real world. The existence of $\sqrt2$ as a real number was postulated because its existence is proven in Euclidean geometry, but there is no reason to believe we live in Euclidean geometry, and lots of reason to think we do not.

There is even some theory that says the real world is discrete, and then not even fractions always "exist" in the sense of measurable length.

There is a famous quote from Kronecker: "God created the natural numbers, all else is the work of man." That includes rational numbers.

I am not wandering about the existence of irrationals in a mathematical sense, I do know that they exist and their existence was proved consistent. I asked on the deep nature of incommensurability based on Euclid's axioms and it seems by your reply that it is not an interest for mathematicians. I do not think so because I know that Euclid's geometry is an abstract model, a mathematical construction, so the properties that devise from it could be somehow dissected.

As far I know, nobody yet did that on the specific problem I proposed. Everybody just say 'they exist, here's the proof, deal with that' but do not explore the properties on how they cause the incommensurability existence.
Also, I intentionally used ancient terms to try not to create bias towards the modern point of view. I really wanted one puts himself at ancient Greece and thought from the problems they faced, even if only modern math could explain the things.

Clarify the question. That means editing the question. People shouldn't have to read all the comments to understand your question. Use modern language, as much as possible.
